# Crm Web Api invalid 304 Response for Expand Entity

Tags: http, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm calling a Crm Web Api query with an expand:

```
https://something.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/systemusers(F437A25E-8D81-E511-80E1-3863BB367DC0)?$select=systemuserid&$expand=new_relatedemployee($select=new_lalicense,new_lalicenseexpiration)
```

When called for the first time from Chrome with caching enabled gives a valid 200 response.  Calling a second time gives a 304 Not Modified response.  So far so good.  But if I update the `new_relatedemployee` entity's attributes in the expand, I still get a 304 response, and the expanded attributes are old and not the current value.  Updating the source SystemUser entity clears the 304 issue, and retrieves the new value.

So basically 304 responses are being returned only for the main entity being queried, and not for the expanded entity.  I would expect both should be being checked.

Is there any way to force the non-cached version from the client?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a known limitation. You can try this query as workaround

`/systemusers?$filter=systemuserid+eq+F437A25E-8D81-E511-80E1-3863BB367DC0&$select=systemuserid&$expand=new_relatedemployee($select=new_lalicense,new_lalicenseexpiration)`

The entity-set query response does not contain the `Etag` header. So the browser will not have anything to put in `If-None-Match` request header in subsequent requests.